# Android locale_config.xml Unbound Prefix Error

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently pentesting an Android app. I decompiled the app without any issues and whenever I try to recompile it back, the apktool.jar throw `Unbound Prefix Error` from the `locale_config.xml` file. Checked the syntax and they're all okay. I don't have any clue on what's going on.

```
W: C:\platform-tools\patch-apk\swifty\base_SAP\res\xml\locales_config.xml:3: error: unbound prefix.
W: C:\platform-tools\patch-apk\swifty\base_SAP\res\xml\locales_config.xml: error: file failed to compile.
Failed!!!
```

Here's the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config>
...
    <locale android:name="en-CA" />
    <locale android:name="en-GB" />
    <locale android:name="en-XC" />
    <locale android:name="en-IN" />
    <locale android:name="en-AU" />
    <locale android:name="zh-HK" />
...
</locale-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pentesting purposes, you might want to just get rid of `localeConfig`.

To do this with minimal changes:

1. Comment out all the `<locale android:name="..." />` lines in `locales_config.xml`.
2. Remove `android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"` attribute of the `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Update `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` version in the build.gradle file to **version 33** or higher to fix the problem

```
android {
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.app"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 33
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```